# Disable link with the prototype observe method

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to create a link like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">text</a>
```

and replace the behavior so that the link downloads the content with Ajax instead when clicking.

It is important for me not to replace the href attribute (so copying the link still works).

One solution would be to do:

```
$('link').onclick = function() { return false; };
```

but I would like to use the .observe method. But this doesn't work:

```
$('link').observe('click', function() { return false; });
```

(which is quite logical).

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you got your answer. The courtesy at this point is to accept one by clicking the large checkbox next to the answer you found most helpful.

Comment: Yeah sorry! I'm new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$('link').observe('click', function(e) { Event.stop(e); });

or

```
$('link').observe('click', function(e) { e.stop(); });
```

or

```
$('link').observe('click', Event.stop);
```

Comment: Cool... didn't know `Event.stop`. That's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 11):

You have to use the event object to achieve this with prototype.

```
$('link').observe('click', function(event) { event.stop() });
```